# Firestore realtime listener detect the type of change for a single doc only

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I saw on the [Firestore documentation for realtime listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) that we can view changes between snapshots and see whether each document is added, removed or modified.

I am wondering if it is possible to see the type of changes if I am only attaching `onSnapshot` to a single document?

I tried to run the `docChanges()` method on the single doc listener:

```
    db.collection("matching").doc("user1").onSnapshot(async doc => {
        doc.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
            if (change.type === "added") {
                console.log("added: " + change.doc.data());
            }
        })
    })
```

But it produced an error of :

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: doc.docChanges is not a function
```

I think I simply cannot run `docChanges()` on a single doc listener. In that case, how to view changes for a single firestore doc realtime listener then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the API will not indicate to you what data or fields changes between snapshots.  You just get a callback every time something changed anywhere in the document.  You have to compare the previous and current snapshot to figure that out for yourself.

Comment: this firebase documentation suggests you can listen to only document updates, ignoring creation and deletion events? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots

but doing this gives the error: `Uncaught TypeError: snapshot.docChanges is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

This `docChanges()` method is applicable on listeners being run on the collection rather than documents, so if you want to check changes between the snapshot put the `docChanges()` after the collection reference.